# Disable CSS transformation-based centering with Jquery depending on content height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For a website I'm designing directly with CSS and Foundation 5, I am centering all content vertically in the middle of the viewport when the content area is taller than the browser window.

I found an excellent [pure CSS solution](http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center) that works perfectly. I'm very happy with the current behavior when the content area is small enough to fit entirely within the viewport without a scroll fold. I fairly sure that I don't need or want any kind of vertical centering when the content is long enough for scrolling.

The problem is that when there is too much content to fit on the screen, the CSS crops off the header and makes it impossible to scroll up to see the top of the content.

The CSS I adapted from davidwalsh.name uses a transformation to raise the container by half its height after its top was placed 50% down from the top.

```
#non-framework-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#non-framework-wrapper {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This is applied to these two nested containers around the Foundation classes.

```
<div id="non-framework-container">
    <div id="non-framework-wrapper">
        <header class="row">
            [...]
        </header>
        [...]
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to disable the CSS when the content (specifically #non-framework-container) is taller than the viewport. I was hoping it would be as simple as this bit of JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function) {
    if ( $("#non-framework-container").height() > $(window).height() ) {
        $("#non-framework-wrapper").css("position":"static", "top":"0", "transform":"none");
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, my script doesn't do anything, no matter the amount of content or the browser size (and regardless of whether I load it in the head tag or at the bottom of the body tag).

I love how the CSS transformation method works, so I'm reluctant to try a pure JavaScript solution.

Comment: does it enter the if statement?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I'm not certain that the the if-statement is working. If it is, it should theoretically run the .css() JQuery function to change the properties I specify, right?

Comment: You can check via an alert or console log easily.

Comment: No, it's not reporting a log inside the if block. Instead, the console says "SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters" at the start of the actual code. Not the first line of the file, but the line of $(document).ready.

Comment: Also, JQuery is included from the Foundation production directory -- /js/vendor/jquery.js -- at the bottom of <body>

Comment: You are missing a ( after function in .ready

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested, cannot currently test where I am):

```
HTML:
<div id="non-framework-container">
    <div id="non-framework-wrapper">
        <header class="row"> 
            <h1>Your mom makes the best pizza</h1>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>


CSS:
#non-framework-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.transform {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}


JAVASCRIPT:
var div = $("#non-framework-wrapper").height();
var winSize = $(window).height();

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (div < winSize) {
        $("#non-framework-wrapper").addClass('transform');
    } else {
        $("#non-framework-wrapper").removeClass('transform');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll try removeClass, but now I see that the real problem is that div and winSize seem to always be the same value. Thanks, though.